# Combine SPF record with and without rules/mechnisms

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, mx-record

I'm very new to DNS world, and now I'm supposed to add an SFP record like `v=spf1 mx include:_spf.blah.com ~all` to an existing SPF record on a zone.

existing `TXT` looks like this :

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.blah1.com
include:_spf.blah2.com include:mail.blah3.com ~all
```

I've read some threads (and about SPF itself a bit) but my question is how should I handle `mx` rule/mechanism in `v=spf1 mx include:_spf.blah.com ~all` properly ?

does this look correct?

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.blah1.com
include:_spf.blah2.com include:mail.blah3.com
mx include:_spf.blah.com ~all
```

if so, is there a difference with this ? (both [validated](https://vamsoft.com/support/tools/spf-syntax-validator))

```
v=spf1 mx include:_spf.blah1.com
include:_spf.blah2.com include:mail.blah3.com
include:_spf.blah.com ~all
```

Any comments/explanation (with potentially a references so I can educate myself better) is really appreciated!

Comment: mxtoolbox.com is very useful when diagnosing mail server issue and also offer an SPF & DMARC generator. The words "include" are unnecessary, for example; "v=spf1 a mx a:mail.example.com ip4:MAILSERVERIPADDRESS -all" will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [Section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.4) of the proposed [SPF RFC (7208)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208), you'll notice that "mx" is a mechanism and "include" is another mechanism, so is does not matter the order that they appear.

But, for speed as shown in [Section 4.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.2), put the mechanisms that may be checked more often at leftmost because the mechanisms are considered from left to right.